# Are non-EU PhD scholarships for a non-eu student taxable in France?

Tags: phd, funding, france

I am a non-eu student. I have a PhD admission from a French university where the funding will come from an institution at my country (outside of the EU) who will pay me directly.

My question is the monthly stipend that I would receive will be taxable in France? If yes, how do I find out which bracket I am in?

This question is similar to [Are PhD scholarships and assistantships taxable?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/are-phd-scholarships-and-assistantships-taxable), however it is specific to France’s case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the source of funding and your nationality are irrelevant with respect to taxation. You will be a French resident because you will be living in France, I assume, and you will thus be taxed on your income. (There may be an exception if your stipend is taxed in your home country and France has signed a treaty with your country to prevent double taxation. This is a rather niche case.) This webpage has a lot of information about taxes when you are a student: https://www.etudiant.gouv.fr/fr/impot-sur-le-revenu-le-cas-des-etudiants-1837 In short, very few sources of income are tax exempt. A salary for working as PhD student is not part of it.

The tax brackets are available here: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1419 note that the tax rates shown are the [marginal tax rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_rate#Marginal), not the total tax rates. There is also a simulator available there, in case you have other sources of income to declare and would like a comprehensive assessment: https://simulateur-ir-ifi.impots.gouv.fr/calcul_impot/2022/index.htm

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I am sorry I don’t have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: @N.I. Hi, I have a similar question. If your total income was below the limit, do you still need to file a tax return?

Comment: @prada yes you do.